# Python can't enter fieldvalue as string

Tags: python

Trying to use a simple dialog to enter information but it's not allowing me to use the `fieldValue` that I  use to enter within the dialog.

Error message below:

```
driver.get("https://" + fieldValues + "/test/")
```

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Script below:

```
import re
import easygui
from pprint import pprint
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


msg = "Please enter the server to test...",
title = "Local Server Tester ",
fieldNames = ['Server URL'],
fieldValues = [],  # we start with blanks for the values
fieldValues = easygui.multenterbox(msg,title, fieldNames),



# Get server from fieldValues
print ("Server to test", (fieldValues))


# Log into system 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://" + fieldValues + "/test")
```

Comment: try `''.join(list(fieldValues))`

Comment: What is inside `fieldValues`and what you want to get?

Comment: Inside fieldValues is going to be whatever is input into the dialog box - so for example 'google.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify this line and it should work,(If you have only one URL to test)

```
driver.get("https://" + fieldValues[0][0]+ "/test")
```

Your fieldvalue is looking something like this.It's a tuple which have a list of single string

```
FieldValues= (['www.yourserver.com'],)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this `tuple` to a new `string`, you can create a string from it as:

```
driver.get("https://" + str(fieldValues) + "/test/")
```

You should make sure that the string representation of fieldValues is what you really want, and if not write a function to unpack the tuple and create a properly formatted string from its elements.

EDIT: given the limited context, you probably are looking for something like this to unpack the tuple values and separate them with '.', assuming that the fieldValues are parts of a domain name:

```
driver.get("https://" + '.'.join(fieldValues) + "/test/")
```